# Best way to trim protruding adhesive from motorcycle tankpad

Tags: motorcycle

The adhesive stickers protrude past the edge of my tank pads.
Any suggestions on the best way to trim the adhesive without damaging the tank paint?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: I have not found any way to do this while the tank pads are on the tank. The only solution I got to work was to remove the pads, and buy new ones - which I could trim down before sticking them on.

Comment: Can you peel it back and restick? If so perhaps you can peel it back an inch put something under it like a plastic cutting board and use a knife to cut it off against the board. repeat all around

Comment: A new Xacto knife carefully slicing the top layer of adhesive without the blade slicing down to the paint should allow the adhesive to peel away. After starting to slice, pull the strip away. View youtube videos how deerskin are sliced thru fat layers to peel skin away from meat for help.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the suggestions. I got most of the excess gum off by pulling on it and using the edge of a thin plastic id card to remove it. It looks much better.